# can't open .svn\tmp\tempfile.tmp: access is denied while doing commit

Tags: svn

i am getting the below error while doing the commit,

**can't open .svn\tmp\tempfile.tmp: access is denied** .

When i started searching about this error in google, i came to know that may be because of McAfee antivirus, this error may come. Please let me know if there is any impact of McAfee on subversion.
http://blog.mxunit.org/2009/03/cannot-cant-open-svntmptempfiletmp.html.

I am using 1.5.5.14361 subversion. McaFee version is 8.5.

Comment: Why do you repost when the same question was closed already?

Comment: Repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025617/impact-of-macfee-on-subversion-closed

Comment: previously i asked the general question saying like impact of mac a fee on subversion. then i edited it. I didnt get the answer so, i just posted it as separate question

Comment: Well, if you suspect the antivirus, did you try to commit with McAfee disabled to check?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem in linux.

I solved it using below command.

chown -R [myaccount:myaccount] [svn checkout directory]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with Eclipse and Visual SVN. Try to turn off every antivirus (I have more than one) with no result.

Turn out that you cannot commit too many stuffs at the same time. I have lots of files in image directories. I have to revert and ignore those dir. Then commit my code one directory at a time, revert and ignore some dirs/files that I don't really need. Finally, I made it work. Rememeber once you mark it to be added to repository, you need to revert it first before you can add to svn ignore list.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have an tool such as an antivirus or backup which regularly opens files with exclusive access, this kind of problem may occur.

Answer (score 0):

chmod 777 [svn checkout directory]

Or in windows make sure that you have right to write to directory where your project is.
Sometimes after reinstalation windows cut you out from your files if you use NTFS.

Comment: Unless in a dev environment where it's not as critical, it's never good to suggest `chmod 777` on something.  It's better to _fix_ the issue.